# Automapper - IEnumerable and nested collections

Tags: c#, automapper

I have a nested structure that follows this XML, with entities corresponding to the outer, middle & inner objects.

```xml
<MyXml>
  <OuterObject>
    <OuterObjectID>123</OuterObjectID>
    <OuterObjectName>Out1</OuterObjectName>
    <MiddleObjectList>
      <MiddleObject>
        <MiddleObjectID>456</MiddleObjectID>
        <MiddleObjectName>Middle1</MiddleObjectName>
        <KeyRelatedToChildInnerObjects>InnerObjKey1</KeyRelatedToChildInnerObjects>
        <InnerObjectList>
          <InnerObject>
            <InnerObjectID>789</InnerObjectID>
            <InnerObjectName>Need_to_map_based_in_InnerObjKey1</InnerObjectName>
          </InnerObject>
          <InnerObject>
            <InnerObjectID>654</InnerObjectID>
            <InnerObjectName>This_too_InnerObjects_are_from_different_entity</InnerObjectName>
          </InnerObject>        
        </InnerObjectList>
      </MiddleObject>
    </MiddleObjectList>
  </OuterObject>
  <OuterObject>
    ...
  </OuterObject>
</MyXml>
```

I'm trying to set the values of and populate the InnerObject collection using AutoMapper.  These will come from a different entity/table, and will be related by the key stated in it's parent MiddleObject.  I have entities/DTOs that correspond to OuterObject and MiddleObject but am having trouble getting the InnerObject mapped.  Thanks for any help.

Comment: Try to look at this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6543659/automapper-to-create-object-from-xml

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I mapped the entiites InnerObjects collection to the corresponding InnerObjects collection on the DTO, based on other posts found here.