# Automapper configuration in XML File

Tags: automapper, xml-configuration

I want to know 2 things with AUtomapper.
Is it possible to store the mapping outside i.e. in a XML file or database?
Can I get some pointers for the same?

Comment: Can someone help me with the same?

Comment: What do you mean by : "can I get some pointers for the same?" ?

Comment: I mean some help on the same.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to define AutoMapper mapping outside code i.e. in a XML file or use different approach for a fully configurable object mapping?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19179459/how-to-define-automapper-mapping-outside-code-i-e-in-a-xml-file-or-use-differen)

Comment: You can't do it out of the box (use an XML file). On the other hands there are other questions on SO that show you how to do it manually: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19179459/how-to-define-automapper-mapping-outside-code-i-e-in-a-xml-file-or-use-differen or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6543659/automapper-to-create-object-from-xml